# Meu input radio está repetindo

Tags: php, html, html5

Meu input radio só nesta linha 3 está repetindo os outros não. Segue imagem para melhor entendimento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Trecho do código onde se repete...

```
<div class="section4">
        <td>Cumprimento de Horário (pontualidade dos horários de viagens).</td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name=" horario" value="A"/> </td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name=" horario" value="B"> </td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name=" horario" value="C"/> </td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name=" horario" value="D"/> </td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name=" horario" value="E"/> </td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name="horario" value="F"/> </td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name="horario" value="G"/> </td>
        </div>
```

Trecho do código PHP:

```
 $section4 =isset($_POST["horario"])?$_POST["horario"]:"[nao informado]";
```

Comment: Talvez tirar esse espaço do começo do name resolva?

Answer (score 1):

O `name` dos seus rádios estão diferentes. Ou remova o espaço de todos ou coloque espaço em todos.

Como está:

```html
<div class="section4">
        <td>Cumprimento de Horário (pontualidade dos horários de viagens).</td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name=" horario" value="A"/> </td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name=" horario" value="B"> </td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name=" horario" value="C"/> </td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name=" horario" value="D"/> </td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name=" horario" value="E"/> </td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name="horario" value="F"/> </td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name="horario" value="G"/> </td>
        </div>
```

Como deveria ficar:

```html
<div class="section4">
        <td>Cumprimento de Horário (pontualidade dos horários de viagens).</td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name="horario" value="A"/> </td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name="horario" value="B"> </td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name="horario" value="C"/> </td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name="horario" value="D"/> </td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name="horario" value="E"/> </td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name="horario" value="F"/> </td>
        <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name="horario" value="G"/> </td>
        </div>
```

Note que removi os espaços, e ficou tudo `name="horario"`.

> Apenas uma lembrete, se está usando tabela, não há necessidade dessa `div`, nem é normal fazer isso.

Answer (score 0):

É o nome que alguns tem um espaço e outros não.
Altere para.:

```
<tr class="section4">
    <td>Cumprimento de Horário (pontualidade dos horários de viagens).</td>
    <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name="horario" value="A"/> </td>
    <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name="horario" value="B"> </td>
    <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name="horario" value="C"/> </td>
    <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name="horario" value="D"/> </td>
    <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name="horario" value="E"/> </td>
    <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name="horario" value="F"/> </td>
    <td WIDTH=9 align="center"> <input type="radio" name="horario" value="G"/> </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: blz Tiago,vou testar.. e a div.. é pq eu chamo ela no php ..como variavel section.. não sei se é certo..

Comment: Como disse @Randrade e muito bem estar a div é estranho. Não gostaria de ter tr? editei a resposta. Na sua pergunta coloque o php assim podemos ajudar.

Comment: Alterei.. e coloquei os tr's ficou ótimo !! obrigado.  Estou vendo agora e pesquisando como posso gerar um xml depois de inseridas estas informações...